# How to recognize bits/stdc++.h in c++ with clangd? I use g++ compiler

Tags: neovim, lsp

[image: error screenshot]

bits/stdc++.h isn't recognized by lspconfig, so I tried just including the string header, for example, but the lspconfig still says "unknown type name 'string'". Any fixes? I use `nvim-lspconfig`.

Comment: Welcome to Vim :-). I believe you question is more about C++ than about Vim.

Comment: Maybe the problem is at `using namespace std;`. Did you tried replacing `string` by `std::string`?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt I think they're trying to _include_ the <string> header. namespacing would come later. And OP, nvim's lspconfig demands the user to understand what the client's requirements are. Which means you'll have to get down and dirty: look for the problem by binary divide and conquer. If pressed for time, I suggest simply using `:make` and going about your day. (I struggle daily to set up lsp, and inevitably abandon it; every; single; day.)

Answer (score 1):

This is not an issue, clangd doesn't know where your header files you are using are located.

Include the path to your header files by setting environment variable `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` to the correct path, then `clangd` should recognize headers in standard library and even the headers specific to gcc/g++ (if your header path include them)

You can do this on Linux by adding this line in `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` (make sure you enter the correct path)

```bash
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/c++/11:/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/11
```

For other platforms, you can definitely look up how to set environment variables on the web.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my issue.